# ReferenceError: gapi is not defined, Capacitor v3, Ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, google-authentication, capacitor

Im having a lot of trouble fixing this error, Im using GoogleAuth and Capacitor v3, and Im doing all this in Ionic and Android,
I was following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rs1imvTbeN0&t=506s and https://enappd.com/blog/google-login-in-ionic-capacitor-app-with-angular/178/

[image]

This is the code for the log in page

```
import { GoogleAuth } from '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';
......
async doLogin() {
    const user = await GoogleAuth.signIn();
    if (user) { this.goToHome(user); }
  }
```

The MainActivity.java looks like this

```
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        registerPlugin(GoogleAuth.class);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a few steps like adding

```
GoogleAuth.init();
```

and

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{your client id here}">
```

on index.html

Heres the blog that helped me, https://enappd.com/blog/google-login-in-ionic-capacitor-app-with-angular/178/